# jquery readmore and less toggle

Tags: jquery

When I click on 'more' it works but the screen goes on the top. Also it displays 'close' at last. After clicking on close again it remains 'close'. I want it to return to 'more'. How can I do that?

```
<p class="disp-cont">
    Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
</p>
<p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
    Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loan, an expert mortgage broker can help you achieve your objective in the simplest and easiest way! For the uninitiated, here’s a sneak peek on <strong>what is mortgage broking?</strong><br>
    Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender (bank & non-bank). While on one hand, the loan specialist assists the borrower to qualify for a mortgage, on the other hand, he negotiates with the lender on the borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to explore your options of financing/refinancing till the deal is finalized. 
</p>
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>
```

```js
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle();
    $(this).html('close');
});
```

Comment: please add a working jsfiddle

Comment: i m learning jquery. what is jsfiddle

Comment: Looks like you have been given an assignment. this is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: it's a really great tool for online prototyping html/css/js. You can save drafts and share the link with other people, like stackoverflow. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: so what i have to do in this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x27knnz1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop the scroll position being moved to the top of the page call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the click handler. To toggle the text you can provide a function to `text()` which sets the value based on it's current text. Try this:

```js
$('.more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'close' ? 'more' : 'close';
  }).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="disp-cont">
  Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
</p>
<p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
  Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loan, an expert mortgage broker can help you achieve your objective in the simplest and easiest way! For the uninitiated, here’s a sneak peek on <strong>what is mortgage broking?</strong>
  <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender (bank & non-bank). While on one hand, the loan specialist assists the borrower to qualify for a mortgage, on the other hand, he negotiates with the lender on the
  borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to explore your options of financing/refinancing till the deal is finalized.
</p>
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>

<p class="disp-cont">
  Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
</p>
<p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
  Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loan, an expert mortgage broker can help you achieve your objective in the simplest and easiest way! For the uninitiated, here’s a sneak peek on <strong>what is mortgage broking?</strong>
  <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender (bank & non-bank). While on one hand, the loan specialist assists the borrower to qualify for a mortgage, on the other hand, he negotiates with the lender on the
  borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to explore your options of financing/refinancing till the deal is finalized.
</p>
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>
```

Comment: thanks  a lot . code is now working

Comment: if i want multiple toggle in one page . than what should i can use

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow so i m unaware about upvote/accept

Comment: can i use <ul> in <p> tag ?

Comment: <p class="disp-cont">
  Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
</p>
<p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
  Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loan, an expert mortgage broker can help you achieve 
  <ul></ul>
</p>
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>

Comment: its not working in my side

Comment: Well, you've not got any content in the `ul`. If you have issue with that I'd start a new question.

Comment: please check code now . it is showing ul tag

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Read More/Less Toggle Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <div class="more">
      Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";


    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can see the demo [here](https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA)

Comment: Vote wasn't mine, but this isn't relevant to the code sample the OP gave, and the logic is poor at best.

Comment: ok no problem I just provide the sample script, I think that's why I got negative vote :(

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but

for issue 1:
replace

```
<a href="#" class="more">more</a>
```

with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
```

for issue 2:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle();
  $(this).html($(this).html()=='close'?'more':'close');
});
```